# RestFB how to subscribe to webook

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api, restfb

I'm trying to replicate the following request (which I elaborated with the Facebook graph explorer)

`POST /{page_id}/subscribed_apps?subscribed_fields=feed,mention`

with it's accompanying page access token. The response I get from that request is

```
{
  "success": true
}
```

How do I make that same request using RestFB? So far I've managed to come up with:

```
FacebookClient client = new DefaultFacebookClient(pageAccessToken, Version.VERSION_8_0);
JsonObject result = client.publish(
    String.format("/%s/%s", pageId, "subscribed_apps"),
    JsonObject.class,
    Parameter.with("subscribed_fields", "feed,mention"));
```

But all I get is:

```
com.restfb.exception.FacebookOAuthException: Received Facebook error response of type OAuthException: (#100) Parameters do not match any fields that can be updated (code 100, subcode null) 'null - null'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make this more easy and readable, I suggest you try this code:

```
FacebookClient client = ne DefaultFacebookClient(pageAccessToken, Version.LATEST);
GraphResponse result = client.publish("me/subscribed_apps",
     GraphResponse.class, 
     Parameter.with("subscribed_fields","feed,mention"));
if (result.isSuccess()) {
  // do some stuff
}
```

That way, you don't need the `page id` and no `String.format`. The page id is already connected to the page access token and sometimes this leads to better working results.

RestFB provides a special object for this kind of requests called `GraphResponse`. It's a simple object that provides some convenience methods. As long as you don't get a complete object back, like a user or post, this is a better way ;)

Comment: Thank you, this ended up working. Idk exactly what was the problem.

Comment: From my experience, it makes sometimes a difference if you use `me` or the page id although it should be resolved internally to the same value. So I try `me` first and this leads to the most stable results.